# How to slide out old div and slide in new div with text content in loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to make two divs so that after clicked button old div is slade out and new div with new content is slide in?

My conception but not aligned `inline`:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xuKz/3/)

I found something similar to my conception but for my solution I need infinity loop with dynamically added content: [example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/d4Ruz/) or [example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/rWbFw/)

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit as to what you're trying to do?  Are you trying to alternate which div is slid in?  Example: click 1 slides in element 1 and element 2 goes out.  Click 2 slides element 2 in and element 1 out.

Comment: After clicked button always first div slide out and new div slide in side by side. In this example I'd like alternating div content.

Comment: You want it to alternate between the red and green divs and have them look as though they are side by side is what you are saying?

Comment: Yes I think so but with a new content added by jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few changes I made to the existing code and CSS, but this should do what you want.  I also added a check to the reset button to ensure that the slideOut is not already hidden.  Otherwise, the animation will unhide the element and hide it again.

It is better to put things into the jQuery `$(document).ready()` function to ensure that all of your elements have been loaded before trying to use them.

[New Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/2xuKz/4/)